# Setting image orientation exif data using imagemagick

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, mogrify

I have a set of images with corrupt exif orientation data. I would like to change the orientation of these images using imagemagick. I found the following command `mogrify -set "%[EXIF:Orientation]" BottomRight image.jpg` but it does not seem to work when I inspect the image using `Identify -verbose image.jpg` the orientation data is Undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if/how you can do that with **ImageMagick**, but you might like to use **exiftool** as follows:

```
# Set orientation with exiftool
exiftool -Orientation=3 -n input.jpg
1 image files updated

# Check with **ImageMagick** 
identify -verbose input.jpg | grep rient
Orientation: BottomRight
exif:Orientation: 3
```

Here is a little loop to test all 8 values:

```
for x in {1..8}; do 
   exiftool -Orientation=$x -n input.jpg > /dev/null
   identify -verbose input.jpg | grep Orientation
done

  Orientation: TopLeft
    exif:Orientation: 1
  Orientation: TopRight
    exif:Orientation: 2
  Orientation: BottomRight
    exif:Orientation: 3
  Orientation: BottomLeft
    exif:Orientation: 4
  Orientation: LeftTop
    exif:Orientation: 5
  Orientation: RightTop
    exif:Orientation: 6
  Orientation: RightBottom
    exif:Orientation: 7
  Orientation: LeftBottom
    exif:Orientation: 8
```

Answer (score 6):

With ImageMagick you can do it in the following way:

`mogrify -orient <orientation> *.jpg`

Valid orientations are

```
bottom-left    
right-top
bottom-right   
top-left
left-bottom    
top-right
left-top       
undefined
right-bottom
```

More info [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#orient).

You can use identify to validate your change:

`identify -verbose input.jpg | grep Orientation`